# Navegacion entre pantallas en flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Estoy intentando  navegar a otra pantalla mediante la funcion de Navigator On Pressed para que al presionar el MaterialButton, se conecte a otra pantalla, el problema es que al ingresar el codigo, marca error en "Context".
Adjunto codigo.

```
Widget _boton1(String texto) {
  return MaterialButton(
    child: Text(
      texto,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    ),
 color: Colors.orange[100],
    elevation: 1,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(60),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
    side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
  ),
 onPressed: () {
 
      Navigator.push(context,   //Error en Context
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PaginaPrincipal()),  
      );     
            },
      
  );
}
```

Comment: En donde estás ingresando el widget _boton1?

Comment: El widget _boton1, lo estoy llamando desde una columna, Por ejemplo tengo una coleccion de MaterialButton en columnas, Por ejemplo:      ` Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [_boton1("PaginaPrincipal"), _boton2("Menu")],
                ), `

Comment: Acabé de compartir una respuesta, lo más probable es que estés creando el botón fuera de la clase padre y por eso te bota el error del context

Comment: Es correcto, el botón estaba fuera de la clase, debido a esto marcaba el error. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede que estes poniendo el widget `_boton1` fuera la de clase, asegurate de poner el botón dentro de la clase:

```
class Ejemplo extends StatefulWidget {
  const Ejemplo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Ejemplo> createState() => _EjemploState();
}

class _EjemploState extends State<Ejemplo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text('Hola mundo'),
            _boton1("PáginaPrincipal"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _boton1(String texto) {
    return MaterialButton(
      child: Text(
        texto,
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      color: Colors.orange[100],
      elevation: 1,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(60),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context, 
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PaginaPrincipal()),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```